# In depth explanation of components in sources.list

Tags: ubuntu, apt

I am trying to write Ansible scripts to automate Ubuntu installation on a few VMs.

I eventually ended up discovering about sources.list file, and there is something I'm quite not getting about the components.

So far my understanding is :

- `Main`  All the free & open-source packages managed by ubuntu's official team.
- `Universe`  - All the free & open-source packages managed by community.
- `Restricted`  - All the proprietary packages that Ubuntu's official team end up managing (i.e. drivers).
- `Multiverse`  - All the proprietary packages that managed by community and basically anything that doesn't belong in one of the other (non-free softwares, plugins, ...).

Now, through my research I stumbled upon a few term that basically mean the same as these :  `contrib`  and  `non-free` . Are these just for the old versions of linux ?

Furthermore, can several components fit in a single entry ? Here is a sample of my sources.list :

```
deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu kinetic-updates main restricted
deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu kinetic universe
deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu kinetic multiverse
deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu kinetic-updates multiverse
deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu kinetic-backports main restricted universe multiverse
```

Why do you have both  `main`  and `restricted` in one entry, then `universe` and `multiverse` on two different entries ? If you can add them up, why not put everything on the first line ?

Why is there only multiverse enabled for kinetic-updates ? Don't we want to also upgrade the others packages ? Or is it a choice ?

If so, based on what (as in, what are the criterias on whether we would want to update only multiverse  ? What would it change to update/install everything except a bit more time ?).

Thanks ! :)

Answer (score 1):

Your understanding of Ubuntu repositories is [accurate](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Repositories/Ubuntu). `contrib` and `non-free` are [used in Debian](https://www.debian.org/doc/debian-policy/ch-archive#archive-areas), along with `main`.

Several components can be added to one line, yes; it’s up to you whether you want to combine lines or keep them separate.

Your `sources.list` doesn’t enable only `multiverse` for `kinetic-updates`; the first line in your extract also features `main` and `restricted`.

You should enable the same components across all repositories:

```
deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu kinetic main universe restricted multiverse
deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu kinetic-updates main universe restricted multiverse
deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu kinetic-backports main universe restricted multiverse
```

See [the `sources.list` man page](https://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/kinetic/en/man5/sources.list.5.html) for details of the `sources.list` format. For Ansible-based deployments you might find [the Deb822-style format](https://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/kinetic/en/man5/sources.list.5.html#deb822-style%20format) more useful.